# Extracting variables from an expression

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, variable, faq

I'm looking for a way to extract a list of variables from an expression, for example with an input like:

```
Leff= (mc dm^2 + mc/12*(h^2 + 3 R^2) + ma da^2 + ma/12 La^2)/(mc dm + ma da)
```

I want this output:

```
{mc, dm, ma, da, La, h, R}.
```

The built-in *Mathematica* function `Variables` can do this, but it doesn't work with more complex expressions containing trascendental functions. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more natural to use `{ c, d, a, b, L, h, R}` instead of unreasonable and awful `{mc, dm, ma, da, La, h, R}` ?

Comment: @Artes Mnemonics can often be helpful, as well as using variables whose names are as close as possible to a formula as printed in a textbook or paper.  Let's blame the paper authors and not the coders for bad variable names!

Comment: Related: [(15153)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15153/121)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any built-in symbols in that list, you could simply do:

```
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[Leff, _Symbol, Infinity]
(* {da, ma, dm, mc, La, h, R} *)
```

If you do have symbols from built-in contexts or packages, you can simply pick out only those that are in the `` Global` `` context with:

```
With[{globalQ = Context@# === "Global`" &},
    DeleteDuplicates@Cases[Leff, _Symbol?globalQ, Infinity]
]
```

If you have a different default working context (e.g. local to notebook/cell or in a package), change the pattern test to the following, instead of `globalQ`:

```
currentContextQ = Context@# === $Context &
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 21):

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
Reduce`FreeVariables[(mc dm^2 + mc/12*(h^2 + 3 R^2) + ma da^2 + ma/12 La^2)/
                     (mc dm + ma da)]
   {da, dm, h, La, ma, mc, R}
```

Answer (score 12):

The below code for `getAllVariables` was lifted without attribution from [some StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846644/utility-to-extract-variables-from-an-expression/5849071#5849071).

```
headlist = {Or, And, Equal, Unequal, Less, LessEqual, Greater, 
   GreaterEqual, Inequality};

getAllVariables[f_?NumericQ] := Sequence[]
getAllVariables[{}] := Sequence[]
getAllVariables[t_] /; MemberQ[headlist, t] := Sequence[]

getAllVariables[ll_List] := 
 Flatten[Union[Map[getAllVariables[#] &, ll]]]

getAllVariables[Derivative[n_Integer][f_][arg__]] := 
 getAllVariables[{arg}]

getAllVariables[f_Symbol[arg__]] := 
 Module[{fvars}, 
  If[MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction] || MemberQ[headlist, f], 
   fvars = getAllVariables[{arg}],(*else*)fvars = f[arg]];
  fvars]

getAllVariables[other_] := other
```

Example:

```
Leff = (mc dm^2 + mc/12*(h^2 + 3 R^2) + ma da^2 + ma/12 La^2)/(mc dm +
     ma da)
getAllVariables[Leff]

(* Out[254]= {da, ma, dm, mc, ma, da, ma, La, mc, dm, mc, h, R} *)
```

Comment: Daniel, since questions are generally not being migrated any longer and since these valuable posts ultimately fall outside our control, why don't you repost your method as a full answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Done. (But if you were a real wizard, couldn't you just make it magically happen?)

Answer (score 9):

If you have even more complicated expressions, you might want to use `Heads -> True`.

```
expr = {f, Subscript[g, i], h[i[j[a, b]]], s'[t] == u[t] + v[t]};

Union @ Cases[expr, Except[__Symbol?(Context @ # === "System`" &), _Symbol], {1, ∞},
              Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {a, b, f, g, h, i, j, s, t, u, v}
> ```

Without checking heads:

```
Union @ Cases[expr, Except[__Symbol?(Context @ # === "System`" &), _Symbol], {1, ∞}]
```

> ```
> {a, b, f, g, i, t}
> ```

Comment: This is the method I would use, expect perhaps as ``Union @ Cases[Leff, s_Symbol /; Context[s] =!= "System`", -1]``

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've tried to provide code that is sufficiently different from rm-rf-s version not to give room for any comments on plagiarism :)

Comment: Thank you, the expressions I usually work with are not so complicated but I might need this sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = (mc dm^2 + mc/12*(h^2 + 3 R^2) + ma da^2 + ma/12 La^2)/(mc dm + ma da); 
Level[expr, {-1}] /. x_?NumericQ :> (## &[]) // DeleteDuplicates
(* {da,ma,dm,mc,La,h,R} *)
```