# Two ways to speed up slow Integrate[]s? (Can't do either)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, pattern-matching

I run into problems like this all the time on the complicated integrands I pass to `Integrate`.  The following code works but takes a veeery looong time:

```
gau[x_, v_] := (1/Sqrt[2*Pi*v])*E^-((x^2)/(2*v));
f[x] := gau[x + m, B]/2 + gau[x - m, B]/2;
aa = D[f[x]*Log[f[x]], {m, 20}] /. m -> 0 // PowerExpand // Expand;
Integrate[aa, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

There are two ways we could solve that integral in a split second, but I don't know how to do either one with *Mathematica*:

1. Is there someway to direct `Integrate`'s look-ups?  *Mathematica* knows how to solve the problem below, so is there some way to tell *Mathematica* to use THIS relation to solve the hard integral above?

   ```
   Integrate[
      gau[x, B]*x^n, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
      Assumptions -> {B > 0, Element[n, Integers], n > 1}
   ]
   ```

$$
\frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \left((-1)^n+1\right) B^{n/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}
$$

2. Failing that, we could just skip the `Integrate` and use pattern matching to apply the solution above.  That's not very satisfying, but it would work.  But the pattern would have to recognize expressions of the form `Times[Exp[x^2/2B], x^n_Integer, ˂stuff that is not a function of x˃]`. How would one do that?

So...

- Which of those approaches is better?
- How do you do them?
- Is there some even better way?

Comment: You can integrate individual parts of the broken up sum terms: `Integrate[aa[[6]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` for instance. The whole thing: `Integrate[#, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> Re[B] > 0] & /@
  aa` takes about six seconds gives `(1693662244309337702400/(B^10))`

Comment: @Histograms  Thank you, but can you help me understand WHY this is so much faster than direct integration of the full expression as I did?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why Mathematica doesn't break up the integrand sum automatically, but my guess would be that it's only legal to do this if the integrals are continuous. Mathematica doesn't risk proving that so treats it as one giant expression. As I said , not sure.

Comment: @Histograms, to demonstrate the hazard of breaking up infinite integrals of sums, consider the integral over the entire real line of $(\exp(-x^2)+1)+(\exp(-x^2)-1)$, compared to the integral of each summand.

Comment: Whatever method you choose, you can spot-check a particular `answer` for a given `integrand` by comparing, say `N[answer /. B -> 1]` and `NIntegrate[integrand /. B -> 1, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`.

Answer (score 6):

As I've pointed out before in, [Mathematica complaints that convergent integral diverges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61866/mathematica-complaints-that-convergent-integral-diverges/63139#63139) and [How to help MMA to simplify integrands?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65279/how-to-help-mma-to-simplify-integrands/71414#71414), [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) is much faster on integrands that are a sums of terms of the form `polynomial * Gaussian`, provided you convert the Gaussian exponential to normal distributions.  It basically is a built-in version of approach 2 that the OP proposed in the question.  Apparently my answer to the second linked question was too specialized (aimed at a special form of integrand) or opaque to be of use to anyone, including the OP.  :)  So I'll try to break down the steps in a more general way.

(1) Extract Gaussian exponentials from the expanded integrand. They should be on levels 1 and 2; if you feeling lucky, change the level specification in `Cases` from `Infinity` to `2`.  The pattern-check on the exponent of the Gaussians is meant to ensure that it is a quadratic with a leading negative coefficient.  In the OP's case, the coefficient is `-1/(2 B)`, and `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ `` effectively ignores symbols when determining the sign. (One could also use something like

```
Simplify[Coefficient[p, x^2] < 0, And @@ Thread[Integrate`getAllVariables[p, x] > 0]]
```

or supply explicit assumptions that apply to the case at hand.  `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ `` seems simplest and likely to be robust enough.)  So store the exponentials in `ggau`:

```
ggau = DeleteDuplicates@ Cases[
    Expand@ aa, 
    Power[E, p_] /; PolynomialQ[p, x] && Exponent[p, x] == 2 &&
      Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ@ Coefficient[p, x^2], 
    Infinity];
```

(2) Get the coefficients of the Gaussians.  The coefficient arrays should consist of `{0, linearSA}` or the integrand is not expressed as a linear combination of Gaussians.

```
coeffs = CoefficientArrays[
   Expand@ aa /. Thread[ggau -> Array[\[FormalG], Length@ ggau]], 
   Array[\[FormalG], Length@ ggau]];
```

(3) Convert each Gaussian to a `NormalDistribution`.  A Gaussian is off from a normal PDF by a constant factor, which we keep for multiplying the `Expectation` when we integrate.

```
Module[{a, b, c},
  {factors, dists} = Transpose[
    (Check[{c, b, a} = CoefficientList[Last@#, x];
        {Sqrt[π]/Sqrt[-a] Exp[a (c/a - (b/(2 a))^2)], 
         NormalDistribution[-b/(2 a), Sqrt[-1/(2 a)]]},
        (* shouldn't happen - checked in Cases[..] *)
        Throw[$Failed]]) & /@ ggau
    ]
  ];
```

(4) Integrate: We have to compute the expectation for each Gaussian/`NormalDistribution` separately and add the results.

```
Total@MapThread[
  Function[{f, d, c}, 
   f*Expectation[c, x \[Distributed] d, 
     Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Expectation]]]],
  {factors, dists, coeffs[[2]]}]
(*
  (1693662244309337702400 Sqrt[1/B])/B^(19/2)
*)

Simplify[%, B > 0]
(*
  1693662244309337702400/B^10
*)
```

It takes less than 0.1 seconds, a zillion* times faster than `Integrate` in this case (*I left `Integrate` to run for a few hours while I did something else, and it never finished).

---

Here is an attempt to put the above procedure into a general-purpose function.

Examples:

```
gaussianIntegrate[aa, x] // Simplify[#, B > 0] & // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.086, 1693662244309337702400/B^10}
*)
```

It tries to automatically identify the exponentials, but it's not perfect.

```
gaussianIntegrate[(Exp[-x^2] x + (1 + x)^40 Exp[-3 x^2 + a])^2, x]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.028, Null}  *)
```

It's not necessarily faster than `Integrate`, which `Expectation` defaults to on complicated integrands.

```
gaussianIntegrate[Abs@ArcCot[x] Exp[-x^2], x] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {3.224, 1/2 MeijerG[{{1/2, 1}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 1]}  *)
```

It doesn't always parse out the Gaussians, even with help.

```
gaussianIntegrate[Exp[-x^4] Exp[-x^2], x]
gaussianIntegrate[Exp[-x^4] Exp[-x^2], x, "Gaussians" -> {Exp[-x^2]}]
```

Both yield:

> gaussianIntegrate::nnormal: E^(-x^2-x^4) does not expand to a linear combination of normal distributions. Using Integrate.

```
(*  1/2 E^(1/8) BesselK[1/4, 1/8]  *)
```

When writing such a function, you're always thinking about how to anticipate problems.  This led me to start with the `"Gaussians"` option to explicitly specify the exponentials in case it was difficult to identify them automatically.  The problem case above arises because the exponential are automatically combined into a single `Power`.  I would say one should code such cases by hand. Probably `Expectation` will revert to `Integrate` anyway, so there is little benefit to trying to sort it out.  In any case, it not clear at this point that the `"Gaussians"` option is at all useful.  Also, the function below automatically falls back on `Integrate` if it fails to parse the integrand as a linear combination of Gaussians.  This might be convenient or not, but it is certainly not absolutely necessary.

Code:

```
ClearAll[gaussianIntegrate];
Options[gaussianIntegrate] = Join[Options[Expectation], {"Gaussians" -> Automatic}];
gaussianIntegrate::nnormal = 
  "`1` does not expand to a linear combination of normal distributions. Using Integrate.";
gaussianIntegrate::idiv = Integrate::idiv;

gaussianIntegrate[i_, x_ | {x_, -Infinity, Infinity}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{res, integrand, factors, dists, a, b, c, ggau, coeffs},

  integrand = Expand[i];
  res = Catch[

    (* extract gaussian exponentials *)
    ggau = OptionValue["Gaussians"]; 
    If[ggau === Automatic,  (* they should be on levels 1, 2 *)
     ggau = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[integrand,
        Power[E, p_] /; 
         PolynomialQ[p, x] && Exponent[p, x] == 2 && 
          Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ@Coefficient[p, x^2],
        Infinity]];

    (* coefficient arrays should consist of {0, linear} *)
    coeffs = Check[
      CoefficientArrays[
       integrand /. Thread[ggau -> Array[\[FormalG], Length@ggau]], 
       Array[\[FormalG], Length@ggau]],
      Message[gaussianIntegrate::nnormal, i];
      Throw[Integrate]
      ];
    If[Length[coeffs] != 2,
     Message[gaussianIntegrate::nnormal, i]; Throw[Integrate]];
    If[First[coeffs] != 0,
     Message[gaussianIntegrate::idiv, i, {-Infinity, Infinity}]; 
     Throw[$Failed]];

    (* convert gaussians to NormalDistributions *)
    {factors, dists} = Transpose[
      (Quiet[Check[
           {c, b, a} = CoefficientList[Last@#, x],
           Message[gaussianIntegrate::nnormal, i];
           Throw[Integrate],
           {Set::shape}], {Set::shape}];
         If[
          a =!= 0, {Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Sqrt[-a] Exp[a (c/a - (b/(2 a))^2)], 
           NormalDistribution[-b/(2 a), Sqrt[-1/(2 a)]]},
          (* could happen - OptionValue["Gaussians"] not checked *)
          Message[gaussianIntegrate::nnormal, i];
          Throw[Integrate]]) & /@ ggau
      ];

    (* integrate *)
    Total@MapThread[
      Function[{f, d, c}, 
       f*Expectation[c, x \[Distributed] d, 
         Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Expectation]]]],
      {factors, dists, coeffs[[2]]}]

    ];

  (* fall back to Integrate - unnecessary *)
  If[res === Integrate,
   res = Integrate[integrand, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     GenerateConditions -> False, 
     Assumptions -> 
      Integrate`getAllVariables[integrand, x] \[Element] Reals, 
     Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Integrate]]]
   ];

  res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed | Integrate]
  ];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for writing this up, this is very helpful material, and I'm working my way through it up understand it.  I've avoided using the pdf built-ins because there's so much I couldn't figure out how to code when doing complicated expression manipulation.  My gau[x,v] function was punt on my part, and it's only pained me on the occasions I needed a numerical result, like today. I'm learning MMa as I go, and this site is my only access to MMa jocks.

Comment: @JerryGuern You're welcome.  Good luck with your work.  Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `aa` can be simplified from `52` to `12` terms by

```
aa = Collect[D[f[x]*Log[f[x]], {m, 20}] /. m -> 0 // PowerExpand // Expand, x, Simplify]
```

but direct integration by

```
Integrate[aa, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> B > 0]
```

remains painfully slow.  The solution offered by Histograms

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[#, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> B > 0] & /@ aa]
```

in effect is a realization of the first option in the Question, because it carries out on each of the `11` terms the integral displayed in the first option.  The second option in the Question, pattern matching, is realized by

```
FullSimplify[(aa /. Exp[-x^2/(2 B)] x^n_ -> (2 B)^(n/2) Gamma[(n + 1)/2] /. 
    Exp[-x^2/(2 B)] -> Gamma[1/2]) Sqrt[2 B]]
```

Both yield `1693662244309337702400/B^10`.

**Addendum**

The comment by Guesswhoitis suggests still a third approach, performing the indefinite integral and then taking the `Limit` as `x->Infinity`.  (Due to the symmetry of the `Integrate` result, the `Limit` as `x->-Infinity` has the opposite value.)

```
Assuming[B > 0, Limit[2 Expand[Integrate[aa, x]], x -> Infinity]]
```

**Second Addendum**

Since I already have "borrowed" from comments by Histograms and Guesswhoitis, I might as well do the same from the excellent answer by MichaelE2.  A quick application of his approach to the problem at hand is

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2 Pi B] Expectation[aa /. Exp[-x^2/(2 B)] -> 1, 
   x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[B]]]]
```

The `AbsoluteTiming` of each approach is `1.69`, `0.007`, `4.61`, and `0.03`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand what you meant by "it offers Integrate only one approach".  Could you clarify that, because it might be just the info I need.

Comment: @JerryGuern  My wording was imprecise, and  I have modified it.  Also, I added a third approach and their respective timings.

Comment: It works here, but *you have to understand what you're doing*. Blind application of this splitting has tripped many an intrepid researcher.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  True.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Oh, you're saying (for the first approach) that MMA figures out how what method solves the first integral and then tries that method first on the remaining 11 integrals?

Comment: @JerryGuern  Yes.  Apart from a constant factor, the many integrals solved by Histogram's approach are special cases of the second integral in your Question, which you already have demonstrated to work.  By the way, Guesswhoitis gave a good explanation of why `Integrate` does not automatically integrate each term separately.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  I do a lot of "solving" definite integrals with pattern-matching hacks.  It's faster than using Integrate[] but obvious easy to do wrong.  And it always makes me wonder, is this bad programming practice?  Or is MMa just currently at a stage of development where it's just more practical to carefully hack around using Integrate[]?

Comment: @bbgodfrey  The part I didn't know how to do with pattern-matching was excluding terms with other x-dependent factors.  For example, your code would run afoul of (x^2)*Exp[-(x^2)/(2*B)]*Cos[x].

Comment: @JerryGuern  You can build patterns to pick out just about anything, although the procedure might be quite complex.  You are correct that my code would run afoul of any term containing other functions of `x`, but I knew there were none.  I do not necessarily recommend the pattern-matching approach but wanted to answer your question.  I hope you found it useful.

Comment: @Jerry, I think of manipulations like these like I'm using power tools: I could do wonderful things with them, but I also understand that I can also cause serious damage if I do not have any presence of mind while using them.

Comment: Your "borrowing" works nicely if you know your integrand is a polynomial times a normal pdf, and will work if it is any function times a normal. +1