# How to judge some kind of multinomial?

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

```
   lst1 = {x1, 123, x1 + x2, x2^5, x3^2, 4 x1 - x2, 4/5, (x2 + x4)^2, 1/x4, 1/(x1 + x3)};
```

How can I pick up the some kind of multinomial from lst1 and get lst2 in a simple way,

```
lst2 = { x1 + x2, 4 x1 - x2, (x2 + x4)^2, 1/(x1 + x3)};
```

Comment: `1/(x1 + x3)` is not a multinomial. Are you trying to filter expressions that depend on two or more variables?

Comment: @J.M.  Yes, that's the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the aim is to extract multivariate expressions:

```
Pick[lst1, Length[Variables@#] > 1 & /@ lst1]
```

or as per J.M.:

```
Select[lst1, Length[Variables@#] > 1 &]
```

Comment: `Select[]` is better here, methinks.

Comment: ...and if one wants to cover nonpolynomial expressions, use ``Reduce`FreeVariables[]`` as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121900).

Comment: @J.M. thanks for the instructive comments