# Except[] with levelspec

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional

I am trying to determine all the variables used in list. For This I use:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Cases[l1,_Symbol,-1]]
```

This is great except that `\Pi` etc. are symbols too. I want to add Except to this `Cases` command to discard numeric symbols but I'm not sure where to add it.

I tried different combinations, but I either get errors, or it will interpret it differently to what I intended.

Alternatively, is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Something like DeleteDuplicates[Cases[l1 , _?(Not[NumericQ[#]] &), {-1}]]? Observe the curly brackets around the level specification.

Comment: What about `Variables`?

Comment: @FredSimons In such cases, I really like operators: `_?(Not@*NumericQ)`

Comment: @Kuba I agree, with both your comments.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to add it as answer?

Comment: @Fred Would you care to post an answer?

Comment: Depending on what exactly is desired from "variables", question and responses in [this prior post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression) might be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example, let us consider the following expression:

```
expr= Log[ 3 Sin[x] + 2 Exp[Pi+ 4 a b + 1/7]];
```

This is not a polynomial, so the function `Variables` cannot be used. On level -1 we have the atoms:

```
Cases[expr,_, {-1}]

(* {2,E,1/7,4,a,b,\[Pi],3,x} *)
```

Observe that 1/7 is an atom! We restrict ourselves to symbols:

```
Cases[expr,_Symbol, {-1}]

(* {E,a,b,\[Pi],x} *)
```

This is not restrictive enough; we only want the symbols that do not have a value. Using Kuba's advice to use function composition:

```
Cases[ expr, _Symbol?(Not @*  NumericQ), {-1}]

(* {a,b,x} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WolframLanguageData` with `Alternatives` to built the `Except`.

```
numConstFunc = Except[Alternatives @@ Symbol /@
    WolframLanguageData[
      EntityClass[
       "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", "NumericConstantFunctions"}], 
     "Name"], _Symbol];
```

Then

```
expr= Log[ 3 Sin[x] + 2 Exp[Pi+ 4 a b + 1/7]];

Cases[expr, numConstFunc, {-1}]
(* {a, b, x} *)
```

Hope this helps.