# Extracting attributes from a function

Tags: pattern-matching

From an expression describing a mathematical function, I would like to extract its parameters.
For example, from the expression `4 Sin[2 a x^2 + b x + c]`, assuming that `x` is the function variable, I would like to have `{a,b,c}`.

I tried using patterns with `FixedPoint` and the `TreeForm` to select the leaves with heads corresponding to `Symbol` (but `x`), but unfortunately unsuccessfully.

Comment: This gets you most of the way there: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression

Comment: Related: [105332](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105332/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = 4 Sin[2 a π x^2 + b x + c] + d E^f;

Cases[Level[expr, {-1}], Except[x, _Symbol?(! NumericQ[#] &)]] // Union

(*  {a, b, c, d, f}  *)
```

Or

```
Cases[Level[expr, {-1}], Except[x | _?NumericQ, _Symbol]] // Union

(*  {a, b, c, d, f}  *)
```

Comment: Works great, thank you ! Be careful to delete duplicates if there is twice a symbol occurring.

Comment: @Mammouth - use `Union` instead of `Sort`. Modified above.