# Error in the exercise or in mathematica settings

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

I am going through Kenneth Rosen's book about discrete mathematics. Chapter 1 there is a example where we build functions to check valid conclusions.

Here is the code:

```
validQ[A_] := Module[{premiseList, premises, i},
premiseList = A[[1 ;; -2]];
premises = Apply[And, premiseList];
TautologyQ[Implies[premises, A[[-1]]]]
]
```

---

```
allCompound[vars_] := Module[{p, q, tempList = vars, propList},
Do[AppendTo[tempList, ! p], {p, vars}];
propList = tempList;
Do[If[! TautologyQ[p && q] && ! TautologyQ[! (p && q)], 
AppendTo[propList, p && q]];
If[! TautologyQ[p || q] && ! TautologyQ[! (p || q)], 
AppendTo[propList, p || q]];
If[! TautologyQ[Implies[p, q]] && ! TautologyQ[! Implies[p, q]], 
AppendTo[propList, Implies[p, q]]]
, {p, tempList}, {q, tempList}];
DeleteDuplicates[propList]]
```

---

```
findConsequences[premises_, level_] := 
Module[{vars, P, possibleC, conclusions = {}, c, i},
vars = getVars[premises];
possibleC = vars;
For[i = 1, i <= level, i++, possibleC = allCompound[possibleC]];
Do[
If[validQ[Append[premises, c]], AppendTo[conclusions, c]], {c, 
possibleC}
];
conclusions
]
```

---

```
findConsequences[{Implies[p && t, r || s], Implies[q, u && t], 
Implies[u, p], ! s}, 1]
```

This is what I get

```
Do::iterb: Iterator {p$26269,getVars[{p&&t\[Implies]r||s,q\      [Implies]u&&t,u\[Implies]p,!s}]} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

Do::iterb: Iterator {p$26269,tempList$26269} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

Do::iterb: Iterator {c$26268,possibleC$26268} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

General::stop: Further output of Do::iterb will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

{}
```

---

And this is what I should get

```
{! s, p || ! s, p \[Implies] ! s, p || ! q, p || ! u, t || ! s, 
t \[Implies] ! s, t || ! q, r || ! s, r \[Implies] ! s, r || ! q, 
s \[Implies] p, s \[Implies] t, s \[Implies] r, s \[Implies] q, 
s \[Implies] u, s \[Implies] ! p, s \[Implies] ! t, s \[Implies] ! r,
s \[Implies] ! s, s \[Implies] ! q, s \[Implies] ! u, 
q \[Implies] p, q \[Implies] t, q \[Implies] r, q \[Implies] u, 
q || ! s, q \[Implies] ! s, u \[Implies] p, u || ! s, 
u \[Implies] ! s, 
u || ! q, ! p || ! s, ! p \[Implies] ! s, ! p \[Implies] ! q, ! 
p \[Implies] ! u, ! t || ! s, ! t \[Implies] ! s, ! t \[Implies] ! 
q, ! r || ! s, ! r \[Implies] ! s, ! r \[Implies] ! q, ! s || 
p, ! s || t, ! s || r, ! s || q, ! s || 
u, ! s || ! p, ! s || ! t, ! s || ! r, ! s && ! s, ! s || ! s, ! 
s || ! q, ! s || ! u, ! q || p, ! q || t, ! q || r, ! q || 
u, ! q || ! s, ! q \[Implies] ! s, ! u || 
p, ! u || ! s, ! u \[Implies] ! s, ! u \[Implies] ! q}
```

I have even tried this by copy pasting the code from the actual textbook files!

What might be the problem?

Comment: Did you already contact the author?

Comment: No, I have not done that yet. I would like to get this fixed first. I have latest 10.4 version of Mathematica (Student version)

Comment: Reverse-engineering lots of code is not a very attractive venture, and  I would recommend you contact the author, as he might be more interested in fixing bugs than your average user here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't defined the function `getVars`, which is used to define `possibleC`, which forms the iterator on your `Do` list.  I tracked down the definition of `getVars`,

```
getVars[p_] := Module[{L = {p}, i = 1},
  While[i <= Length[L],
    If[Head[L[[i]]] === Symbol,
     i++,
     L[[i, 0]] = List;
     L = Flatten[L]
     ]
    ]
   DeleteDuplicates[L]
  ]
```

But I couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure what version the book was written for, but I did figure out what it was trying to do, which is just list all the `Symobol` objects in the premise, so just use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21259/9490)

```
getVars[p_] := DeleteDuplicates@Cases[p, _Symbol, Infinity]
```

Now the code gives the answer you are looking for.