# Define a function of a function of an arbitrary variable

Tags: functions, function-construction, variable

I want to define a function called `int` that takes another function as an argument and yields an integral of that function from 0 to 1 (just for example).

So I tried:

```
int[f_]:= NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

This now works like this:

```
int[Cos]
0.841471
```

or

```
int[Sin]
0.459698
```

However, if I want a specific function, like `x Sin[E^x]`, I need to write this:

```
int[# Sin[Exp[#]]&]
0.411229
```

How do I define the function `int` so that it will work like

```
int[x Sin[Exp[x]]
```

or

```
int[t Sin[Exp[t]]
```

with any letter as an argument and yield the result?

I tried also this:

```
int[f_[x_]] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

While `int[Sin[t]]` yields the correct result, `int[t Sin[t]]` just returns `int[t Sin[t]]`.

Comment: If you consider the syntax of `Plot`, `Table`, `Integrate`, etc., the variable is specified when the argument is an algebraic expression and not literally a function.  E.g. a syntax of the form `int[t Sin[t], t]` identifies the variable (in the 2nd argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an [automatic extraction of the independent variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135539/22013):

```
int[f_] := With[{var = Reduce`FreeVariables[f][[1]]}, 
  NIntegrate[f, {var, 0, 1}]]
```

so that

```
int[x Sin[Exp[x]]]
```

> 0.411229

but also

```
int[t Sin[Exp[t]]]
```

> 0.411229

And for example:

```
int[Cos@Cos@Cos@zzz]
```

> 0.786287

Comment: Both of your answers are very nice, but I like this one more (I've never heard of FreeVariables)...

Comment: This is pretty cool; can you talk a little about what `Reduce\`FreeVariables[f]`does?  I'm having trouble finding a description of `\`FreeVariables` in the help files.

Comment: If you went to the linked answer, you'd see it's an undocumented function. Btw, for a bunch of undocumented functions see [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Try leaving the "[x]" out of the definition.

```
int[f_] := NIntegrate[f, {x, 0, 1}];
int[x Sin[Exp[x]]]
0.411229
```

If you need to be able to change the variable, you could do:

```
int2[fun_, var_] := NIntegrate[fun, {var, 0, 1}]
int2[x Sin[Exp[x]], x]
0.411229
```