# Extract variables from sum of unevaluted functions

Tags: expression-manipulation, filtering, variable

I have sums of the form

```
sum = a f[1,1,0] + b f[1,2,0] + c f[1,2,1] + ...
```

It is always linear in `f[a,b,c]`. I would like a function that returns a list of all `f[a,b,c]` appearing in the `sum`. Following an answer from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression), I have created the following function, which behaves correctly when evaluated on `sum`:

```
getVariables[expr_, f_] := DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr,f, Infinity];
getVariables[sum, f[_,_,_]] 
(*{f[1, 1, 0], f[1, 2, 0], f[1, 2, 1], ...}*)
```

The problem is that when there's a single function it does not work:

```
getVariables[f[a,b,c], f[_,_,_]] 
(* {} *)
```

It only fails when it's exactly `f[a,b,c]` and works fine for e.g. `2f[a,b,c]`.

What am I missing here? I do not get why it would fail in that case.

Comment: The level specification `Infinity` (which is equivalent to `{1, Infinity}` does not include level `0` (i.e. the whole expression), which is why nothing is found in `f[a,b,c]`. You can use `{0, Infinity}` or `All` instead to also include level `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Lukas Lang's comment, the problem comes from the default level specification of `Cases` and the fact that `f` appears as the head (or rather, at part 0/only in level 0) in `f[a,b,c]`.

From the [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) documentation

> The default value for levelspec in Cases is {1}.

So when a level *is* specified, say for example as `Cases[f[a, b, c], _f, Infinity]`, *Mathematica* implicitly interprets this is `Cases[f[a, b, c], _f, {1, Infinity}]`.  This works great for expressions like your `sum` since it has the form

```
a f[1, 1, 0] + b f[1, 2, 0] + c f[1, 2, 1] // FullForm
Level[%, {1}]
```

> Plus[Times[a, f[1, 1, 0]], Times[b, f[1, 2, 0]], Times[c, f[1, 2, 1]]]
>
> {a f[1, 1, 0], b f[1, 2, 0], c f[1, 2, 1]}

and the stuff you want to work with starts at level 1.

Now with that being said, just the single instance of `f[a, b, c]` has a different structure and its elements on level 1 are

```
Level[f[a, b, c], {1}]
```

> {a, b, c}

So when the above usage of `Cases` (i.e. starting at level 1) is called on this structure, it doesn't see the `f`, and thus doesn't return anything.

Then we return to the `Cases` documentation to see

> Level 0 corresponds to the whole expression.

And there we have our solution.  If we want to search the whole expression, instead of starting at level 1, we need to call `Cases` as

```
Cases[f[a, b, c], _f, {0, Infinity}]
```

> {f[a, b, c]}

Comment: Thanks for expanding @Lukas Lang's explanation, that was indeed the culprit.