# Finding variables in a list of arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

For given data, arrays of table, how one can find the independent terms in Mathematica?

For example, given sets:

```
list={{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,k}}
,{{a2,b2,c2},{d+e,e2,-f},{g,h,k}}
,{{a3,ab3,c*c2},{d2+e2,e,f2},{g2,h2,k}}}
```

I want to find the independent terms, i.e., the output for the above example should be:

> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k, a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,a3,b3

The sets can have arbitrary length, and the arrays might not be the same size. But it is distinguished by, comma, and of course I want to treat $-a$ as $a$ and so on.

Can you provide me with explicit code or some key command for this purpose?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Variables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html)? You can use it directly on your list: ``Variables[list]``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting variables from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression)

Answer (score 7):

```
Variables[list] == (Cases[list, _Symbol, ∞] // Union)
```

Or

```
Variables[
  list] == (Select[Level[list, {-1}], Not@*NumberQ] // Union)
```

> True

Comment: Two plus the comment and counting. Nicely done!

Comment: You are right. `Union` will do so automatically. I have edited this out. Thanks for noticing. @rhermans

Comment: In addition, `Variables` "looks for variables only inside sums, products, and rational powers: `Variables[{x,Sin[y]}]===Cases[{x,Sin[y]}, _Symbol, ∞]` gives `False`, which might be important

Comment: @user1066 Please write it up as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
Union@Select[Level[list, {-1}], Head[#]==Symbol&]
```

Answer (score 6):

The canonical answer has been provided. Time to find 10 more ways of doing it.

Here's the first one

```
complicated = {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, k}}, {{a2, b2, 
     c2}, {d + e, e2, -f}, {g, h, k}}, {{a3, ab3, c*c2}, {d2 + e2, e, 
     f2}, {g2, h2, k}}};
```

Then, the following does the trick

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[List @@@ Flatten[complicated]]] /. 
 a_ /; TrueQ[NumberQ[a]] -> Nothing
```

> `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, a2, b2, c2, e2, a3, ab3, d2, f2, g2, h2}`

Answer (score 5):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Sort@Lookup[GroupBy[Level[list, {-1}], NumericQ, DeleteDuplicates], False]

(*{a, a2, a3, ab3, b, b2, c, c2, d, d2, e, e2, f, f2, g, g2, h, h2, k}*)
```