# Why does FindInstance require specifying variables, and how to transform a list of logical expressions into the list of its variables

Tags: programming, logic

It would be convenient to have a function VarsfromLogical
which out of `{a+b>c,c+d==a}` outputs `{a,b,c,d}`

Incidentally, I use this for detecting the variables for FindInstance[expr,vars], and it might have been convenient for beginners if Mathematica would have offered also the syntax FindInstance[expr], because the vars are uniquely determined by the expr , and so there is no need to be explicit about them. Anyway, this may be achieved via the answers to the similar question [Extracting variables from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression) or by some other instructive answers like Union[Cases[list, _Symbol, ∞]], Variables[Level[list, {-1}]]  and   p = Position[list, _Symbol, Heads -> False]; Extract[p] @ list  Remains the question of why these lovely solutions  are necessary at all in a FindInstance

Comment: This seems the same question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression

Comment: For instance ``Reduce`FreeVariables[{a + b > 0, c + d == a}]`` works (from an answer to the linked question).

Comment: Indeed, one of the answers DeleteDuplicates@Cases[list, _Symbol, Infinity] does the job, together with all the other variants mentioned. Incidentally, I use this for detecting the variables for FindInstance[expr,vars], and it seems convenient for beginners if Mathematica would have offered also the syntax FindInstance[expr], because the vars are uniquely determined by the expr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Union[Cases[list, _Symbol, ∞]]
```

Comment: This works also without Union, just  Cases[list, _Symbol, \[Infinity]],  and also Cases[list, _Symbol, 3]

Comment: @florin What does `Cases[{a + b > 0, c + d == a}, _Symbol, Infinity]` return for you? Also `Union@Cases[{a + b > 0, c + d == a}, _Symbol, {-1}]` might be better than using the level spec `3` (if you want to avoid `Infinity`).

Comment: Both Cases[{a + b > 0, c + d == a}, _Symbol, Infinity] and 
Cases[{a + b > 0, c + d == a}, _Symbol, {-1}]  output {a, b, c, d, a} on my 13.3   Oops, the a appears twice if I don't use also Union, or Variables, so these are necessary

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {a + b > 0, c + d == 0};

p = Position[list, _Symbol, Heads -> False]
```

{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}

```
Extract[p] @ list
```

{a, b, c, d}

Comment: Beautiful! 4 answers showing the beauty of Mathematica:)

Comment: Mikado's and my solution also work with deeply nested lists like `list = {{a + b > 0, c + d == {{g + h}}}}`. You don't have to worry about level-specifications.

Comment: Thanks, I see!  I think I have maybe  digested all the  solutions, except that I would have written yours in a simpler syntax,  as Extract[list, p] ; I still don't understand the point in having the alternative syntax using the prefix operator @

Answer (score 2):

```
Variables@list[[All, 1]]
```

> {a, b, c, d}

---

For a more general case:

```
list = {a + b > 0, c + d == g + h}
v1 = Variables@list[[All, 1]]
v2 = Variables@list[[All, 2]]
Union[v1, v2]
```

> {a, b, c, d, g, h}

Comment: `Variables[Level[list, {-1}]]` is very robust

Comment: As an aside, Level[list, {-1}]  works also. Another issue is  to understand the command Level, which seems rather sophisticated, and in particular the option -1.  Thanks a lot anyway, I'm using this in a FindInstance for a list of many conditions, some nested, and it works!

Answer (score 2):

```
{a + b > 0, c + d == 0};
Variables[List @@@ %]
```

---

```
{a, b, c, d}
```