# Can I define a "total Curl" operator similar to a "total derivative (Dt)" operator?

Tags: vector-calculus

I am trying to take the curl of a vector field.

```
A={A1,A2,A3}
B=Curl[A,{x,y,z}]
```

This yields

```
{0,0,0}
```

because Mathematica thinks that the vector is a constant.  I would like for Mathematica to assume that the vector A varies as a function of position, so I make A1, A2, and A3 functions of [x,y,z] like so:

```
A={A1[x,y,z],A2[x,y,z],A3[x,y,z]}
B=Curl[A,{x,y,z}]
```

Now the output looks like this:

[image: Mathematica Output Image]

which is correct, but I would like to get rid of the [x,y,z] on all of the output terms which clutters up the output and makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Does `B /. f_[x, y, z] :> f` give what you need?

Comment: See [15153](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15153/simplify-function-notation)

Comment: Yes, that works very nicely.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`B /. f_[x, y, z] :> f` will get rid of the [x,y,z,t] on the functions.