# Is there a possibility to keep variables virtual?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

It is general knowledge, that when we deal with derivatives of function in Mma we have to inevitably indicate variables of such functions. Namely, this

```
 D[f[x],x]
```

is correct, while this

```
D[f,x]
```

is not, returning zero.

However, as soon as one has a differential expression, especially one containing multiple partial derivatives one faces a too lengthy-expression. It is often difficult to look at, leave alone to work with.

As a workaround, I imagine that it would be very helpful if one could define a function with virtual variables. Namely, I dream about a possibility to define a variable, say, `f` depending on coordinates `f[x,y,z]` such that the part `[x,y,z]` would be invisible, though Mma is aware of its existance and treat it as if it is written down with the coordinates. In this case,

```
D[f, x]
```

would return

[image]

instead of zero.

If such a definition of virtual variables is possible, the advantage would be in a dramatic shortening of expressions containing differential operations.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50726/1871). My last choice is: for inputs, use `With` e.g. `With[{f=f[x, y, z]}, D[f, x, y]]`; for outputs, use functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15153/1871).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, I personally prefer explicitly use `With` and functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15153/1871) to simplify inputs and outputs related to ODE/PDE, but still, it's possible to achieve what you want, we just need to make use of `$Pre` and `$PrePrint`:

```
Clear[$Pre, $PrePrint];

rule = {u -> u[x, y], v -> v[x, y], p -> p[x, y]};

$Pre = Function[expr, Unevaluated@expr /. rule, HoldAll];

$PrePrint = 
  Function[expr, 
   TraditionalForm[
    expr /. Derivative[inds__][head_][vars__] :> 
       Apply[Defer[D[head, ##]] &, 
        Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}] /.
     Reverse /@ rule]];
```

*The code in `$PrePrint` is a modified version of [`pdConv`](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/).*

Now we can do something like following:

[image]

In the GIF I've directly worked on `TraditionalForm` of the code, you may transform the code to `InputForm` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, or `StandardForm` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

However, do notice the approach has at least one side effect i.e. you can no longer use `u`, `v`, `p` for defining functions:

```
f[u_] := u
```

> Pattern::patvar: First element in pattern Pattern[u[x,y],_] is not a valid pattern name.

Comment: Thank you. Please comment a bit of how do you use the functions `$Pre` and `$PrePrint`. Out of the movie it seems that having once evaluated the code above, you then simply type the operators like `D[u,x]`. Right?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yeah, exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can try anonymous functions. here are some examples:

```
f = #^2 &
(* #1^2 & *)

Derivative[1][f]
(* 2 #1 & *)

f'
(* 2 #1 & *)
```

Or with 3 arguments:

```
f = Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] &
(* Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] & *)

Derivative[1, 0, 0][f]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this is what OP asks for. According to the description in the question, OP is looking for a way to simplify the representation of ODE/PDE.

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. The approach of @xzczd seems to be much closer.