# How to make pdConv not show the independent variables of functions

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting

[`pdConv`](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/) is a very good tool.

How to modify `pdConv` (or a better way is to add an option?) to make the independent variables of the functions not show?

That is, display `u[r,θ,z]` as `u`.

Thank you!

```
pdConv[f_] := 
 TraditionalForm[
  f /. Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :> 
    Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &, 
     Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
        Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}]]
```

Comment: ……`g[vars]` - >`g`

Comment: @xzczd Thank you, your method is feasible, but there is a small flaw, the 0th order derivative still displays the independent variables. Could this be improved by modifying pdConv? :)

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241634/1871 ?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear@pdConv;
pdConv[f_, pat_List] := pdConv[f, Alternatives @@ pat]

defaultpat = _Subscript | _Symbol?(Context[#] === Context[] &);

pdConv[f_, pat_ : defaultpat] := 
 f /. {Derivative[inds__][g : pat][vars__] :> 
     Apply[Defer@
        D[g, ##] &, {{vars}, {inds}}\[Transpose] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
         Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}], (g : pat)[__] :> g} // TraditionalForm
```

Please read the document carefully to understand why the code is modified in this manner.

The function can be used in 2 ways. The one-argument syntax should handle most of the *usual* cases:

```
D[Subscript[f, 1][x, y], x, x] + D[g[x, y], y] + 
  Subscript[f, 1][x, y] + g[x, y] == 0 // pdConv
```

[image]

For edge cases, set a second argument to specify functions whose independent variables should be omitted:

```
pdConv[D[\[FormalA][x, y], x] + D[OverTilde[v][x, y], y] + 
       f[\[FormalA][x, y], OverTilde[v][x, y]] == 0, {\[FormalA], OverTilde[v]}]
```

[image]